# Day 3 My Preserved Limes Are Not Filling the Jar

Tags: storage-method, safety, lime

I packed all the nearly quartered limes I had tightly into a quart jar with plenty of salt. When I finished, there was about 1/3 of the jar empty. I put them in the dark cupboard because I didn't know what else to do. Now I have more limes. Would it be safe to scrub, cut, salt, add them to the jar, and mash them down until the jar is filled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that’s fine. Not much to say here, really. It’s okay to have a head space in the jar (the high acid and salt content makes the limes inhospitable for all microorganisms that might otherwise colonize the surface), and it’s also okay to add more salted limes.

Comment: I'd also suggest squeezing a bunch of lime juice on top, to cover.